# How to search and display content from a random access file?

Tags: c++, filestream, random-access

This code is supposed to search for the iterNo of each client in the file and then display that info.  My problem is that it always displays the first item in the file regardless of what number I search for.   Any help will be appreciated.Really desperate right now... thanks in advance for your response.

```
void View()
{       
    char ans; //answer to store 'y' or 'n'
    Intervention inte;
    int interNo;

    ifstream InfoFile("info.dat", ios::in |ios::binary|ios::app);
    if (!InfoFile)
    {
        cout <<"Error - random files could not be opened.";
    }
    else
    {
        while (true)
        {
            cout << "\nEnter client's interNo number to display ";

            cin >> interNo;

            inte.getClient();
            inte.getAddress();
            inte.getTelNo();
            inte.getTime();
            inte.getDate();
            inte.getAnimal();

            //InfoFile.seekg(sizeof(Intervention)*(interNo - 1));
            InfoFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&inte), sizeof(Intervention));
            //if not eof show data
            if (!InfoFile.eof())
            {
                //Display the processed
                // info for the employee
                inte.display();
            }
            cout << "Enter another employee's information to display ? [y / n] ";
            fflush(stdin);
            ans = ' ';
            while (ans != 'y' && ans != 'Y' &&
                ans != 'n' && ans != 'N')
            {
                ans = _getch();
            } cout << endl;
            if (ans == 'n' || ans == 'N')
            {
                exit(1);
            }

        }//end while

    }//end else

}//end function view
//**********************************************
```

Comment: You're doing nothing to search; you're simply reading the first value from the file with the `read`. (You commented out the line above that, which does move the file pointer.) If you want to locate a specific client, you have to actually move the file pointer from the beginning of the file.

Comment: Truth is I'm not sure where to put that line...if I put it anywhere outside of the (if (!InfoFile.eof()))..then it just goes straight to asking me if I want to display another without displaying anything

Answer (score 0):

Well the code does what it should do. You don't check anywhere if the found Intervention is the one you look for, nor you don't move the file read pointer.

### If you store IDs inside the file

You only read the Intervention once too:

```
InfoFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&inte), sizeof(Intervention));
```

Maybe you meant to **check** if the Intervention has the ID you inputted?

```
while(inte.getID()!=interNo && InfoFile)
  InfoFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&inte), sizeof(Intervention));
```

### If you don't

You need to uncomment the line of code that you must've commented out earlier:

```
InfoFile.seekg(sizeof(Intervention)*(interNo - 1));
```

This line actually should position the `read pointer` to a place in the file, where the given `Intervention` is written. Check out the [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/?kw=seekg) page for more detail on the read pointer.

Comment: I quoted the line you should replace. Substitute the code inside the first snippet for the code inside the second snippet.

Comment: I've encountered another problem..when I enter the number I'm searching it still displays the first item but if I choose yes nd try to display another item, the 2nd item in the file shows..If I choose yes again to display another it displays the info for the number I entered

Comment: I think I missunderstood the conception behind the file itself. My solution would work if you stored IDs in the file, but you probably **don't**. And I didn't really look at the lines you commented out. Check my main answer again in a second please.

Comment: instead of using ur getID I used getInterventionNo becuz I dont have a getID in my program

Comment: Thanks for ur help man..but its still not displaying the right info even after uncommenting that line

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but I think the main problem is with you not understanding what you want to do, or not understanding how things you do actually work. People here can help you find an error in the code, but even if they do - it won't help you when you don't understand how to use the information. It would be probably best for you to just read more about the language and the problem, or pick a less complicated subject to solve.

Comment: Thanks but I have to solve the problem because its an assignment which I need to give in 2morrow